# Rails 5: prepopulate search form inputs using form_with with params without having to do it manually for each field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say we have a simple search form that submits a GET request for searching/filtering:

```
<%= form_with(scope: :search, url: url_for, local: false, method: :get) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
<% end %>
```

When we use `form_with` (or the old `form_for`) with an **ActiveRecord object**, all fields get automatically pre-filled with the current value of the AR object attribute.

But in the example above, if we use only a scope (in our case, `search`), that doesn't happen when we open the page with a URL like so:

`http://localhost:3000/blog?search%5title%5D=test`

Even tough that URL will make rails populate `params[:search]` with `{title: 'test'}` for us, it would still require to pass the value manually for each field, like so:

`<%= f.text_field :title, value: params.dig(:search, :title) %>`

This gets very tedious and error-prone as the search form grows and seems such a common requirement that I can't believe there isn't a more 'rails way' of doing this without resorting to something like the [Form Objects Design Pattern](https://gorails.com/episodes/form-objects-design-pattern).

Isn't there any automatic way of pre-filling those inputs without having to pass the values manually from params?

Comment: Is ransack an option?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a search object? It will behave exactly like ActiveRecord object (in terms of pre-filling the form).

Comment: @SujanAdiga Not really, but I'll keep it in my radar

Comment: @MrShemek Yes, but I'd like to avoid it. The question mentions 'I can't believe there isn't a more 'rails way' of doing this without resorting to something like the Form Objects Design Pattern', which I assume is the 'search object' pattern you mentioned right?

Answer (score 3):

> Search is not a model in my application

You can create as many models as you like. This model will hold the values and logic for your search. When you pass this object into `form_for` it will fill the values that are set for the attributes in the object. Create the following class in your models directory

```
class Search
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :title

  validates :title, presence: true
end
```

- By including the `include ActiveModel::Model` you get logic for 'free'. Such as `Search.new(params)` and it will assign all keys in the params hash to your model attributes (as long as they are defined by  `attr_accessor`
- You get validations which could be pretty handy when you want to give feedback to the user that is using your search form
- Later when your search model gets more logic write unit test for this model

Comment: Chris thanks for you reply, but this is basically the Form Object Design Pattern I mentioned in my question, that I already knew and was looking for alternatives that didn't require defining a class for each form.

Comment: Whats the problem of defining a new class? It’s the basic idea of OO :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a new search object with the values of the params in your controller action. Then the form_with/form_for should pre-fill the input fields. Maybe like this:

`@search = Search.new(params[:search])`

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Search` is not a model in my application. That's why I used `scope: :search` and not `model: :search`.